# Can I manually download Tauri buiding dependencies?

Tags: javascript, rust

Due to some reasons, my host matchine can not get access to the Internet, the only way to build the app is to manually download all dependecies on another disk.
However, I was stuck in the wix package, which is downloaded from github. I've successfully downloaded it from my browser, but I don't know where to place it.

Is there any way to manually download all dependencies?

I was stuck here (on another disk):

```
info: Running Loopback command
   Compiling app v0.1.0 (D:\frontend\src-tauri)
   Compiling tauri v0.6.0
    Finished release [optimized] target(s) in 19.28s
info: Verifying wix package
info: Downloading https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3/releases/download/wix3112rtm/wix311-binaries.zip
```

Comment: I'd argue that a machine without Internet access isn't a good development machine anyway, and you should use a different machine to develop than the restricted one used in production.

Comment: See if "cargo vendor" command helps you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60989162/how-to-list-a-projects-source-files-using-the-cargo-crate

Comment: @mcarton some government work needs to be done on an air-gapped PC and can only have outside code brought in on CDs or some other form of media that can be write locked

Comment: @eric556 and those would allow to use Rust and random libraries? How do they validate that the copy of the compiler and the libraries are safe to bring in the air-gap in the first place?

Comment: @mcarton Actually, this is just a test machine which is hosted in a virtual environment. After all testing, the code then can be deployed to the real  development matchine. I was really stuck in the very first step.

Comment: @mcarton usually bringing new software onto an airgapped system (compiler, libraries, etc.) involves a lot of review. Once it is deemed safe it can come over. Its as much of a pain as it sounds

Comment: @eric556 which is why I was surprised it would use Rust, and some random crates. I would not expect many companies to have gone through that reviewing process at the yet.

Answer (score 1):

On a windows machine, you can put the contents of https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3/releases/download/wix3112rtm/wix311-binaries.zip in `%LOCALAPPDATA%/tauri/WixTools`.